# Why is the amount of slots doesn't match the amount of blocks on mainnet

Tags: rpc, slots, block

The documentation states that a block is:

> A contiguous set of entries on the ledger covered by a vote.
> A leader produces **at most** one block per slot.
> (emphasis mine)

But it doesn't specify what might be reasons for a blockchain skipping producing a block in a slot, and as it can be seen in explorer approximately 10% of slots didn't have blocks in them.

[image: explorer]

I've got two errors while using an official mainnet RPC endpoint, both, as it seems, caused by a fact that a slot didn't have a block in it.

```
RPC response error -32007: Slot 143300000 was skipped, or missing due to ledger jump to recent snapshot

Block 30596283 cleaned up, does not exist on node. First available block: 34365268
```

But I do not completely understand what those errors mean and whether there are some other ways a block can be skipped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slots are a unit of time during which a validator *may* act as leader and produce a block.  There are a variety of circumstances that can lead to this not actually happening, leading to a *skipped slot*. The leader may be offline, too far behind the tip, get interrupted by late data from a previous leader, produce a block on a minority fork, etc.